# js file in maven multi-module without any reason became with mistake

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, spring, maven

I have maven multi module project with spring and hibernate in eclipse. After some time one of files from folder WEB-INF/resources/js became with red icon with shows that there is some mistake. It wasn't first time of this situation. Previously I just delete project and download it from github. What is the reason? Maybe it is bug in eclipse. (no changes to this file wasn't added)

Comment: does it say anything related in problem tab (window > show view > general > other > problem)

Comment: Yes. There is 17 problem, but they appears periodically. I show that file to people who knows js and they said it ok. It seems like  it's problem in eclipse. But I'm not sure.And build is succsesful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could happen because eclipse Javascript syntax check is configured to mark something as ERROR which is not that important for you

goto

```
windows > preference > JavaScript > validator > errors and warnings
```

and tune this properly